# Sort results by a field in another table

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have two tables. The first one is named 'products,' and the second one is named 'variants.' The 'variants' table includes a field called 'product_id,' which points to a product in the 'products' table, and a field named 'price.'

I am using NodeJS and Sequelize to interact with a MySQL database. My goal is to retrieve a list of products and sort it based on the 'price' field from the 'variants' table. However, when I obtain the list of products, it does not match my expectations.

I have also implemented a limit and offset for pagination. Upon checking the query, it returns an SQL query like this:

```
SELECT `Product`.*,
       `variants`.`id` AS `variants.id`,
       `variants`.`price` AS `variants.price`
FROM
  (SELECT `Product`.`id`,
          `Product`.`title`,
          `Product`.`image`,
          `Product`.`view`,
          `Product`.`status`,
          `Product`.`created_at`
   FROM `products` AS `Product`
   WHERE `Product`.`status` != 'delete'
   GROUP BY `id`
   LIMIT 0,
         10) AS `Product`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `variants` AS `variants` ON `Product`.`id` = `variants`.`product_id`
ORDER BY `variants`.`price` DESC;
```

I noticed that after setting the limit to 10 products, the list is sorted by price, but it returns a list with prices starting from 0 instead of higher values like 1000 or 2000. I want to initially sort all products by price and then take the first 10. However, my code seems to be doing the opposite. How can I correct this?

That's what I did:

```
let query = {
        attributes: ['id', 'title', 'image', 'view', 'status', 'created_at'],
        where: {
            status: {
                [Op.ne]: 'delete'
            }
        },
        include: {
            model: Variants,
            as: 'variants',
            attributes: ['price'],
        },
        order: [[{ model: Variants, as: 'variants' }, 'price', 'DESC']],
        group: 'id',
};

//other code

query.limit = payload.limit;
query.offset = payload.skip;



const products = await Product.findAll(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

*you can add a new key query -  order = 'ASC',
*if you need pagination you can add pagination setup like adding limit and count by adding default pagination as 10 u will achieve your out

Comment: Well I tried this, but it seems not to work. But I tried another way is using raw query. Thanks for your idea.